# Add full stochastic curves to quantmod chart

Tags: r, quantmod

Using R and the quantmod package, I am trying to add a full stochastic curve to the chart as it is displayed on http://www.stockta.com, which includes variables: %K(14,3) %D(3).

The documentation for [`addSMI`](http://www.quantmod.com/documentation/addSMI.html) lists four arguments:

```
n       periods
slow    slow
fast    fast
signal  signal
```

I am not sure how I should translate the variables %K(14,3) %D(3) into `addSMI` to get the same stochastic curves as in http://www.stockta.com.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addSMI` adds the stochastic momentum index, not regular stochastics. It doesn't look like there's currently an `addStoch` function, but you can always use `addTA`

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY")
chartSeries(SPY, subset='2015/')
addTA(stoch(HLC(SPY)), col=2:4)
```

[image]

The default values for `stoch` arguments `nFastK`, `nFastD`, and `nSlowD` are the same as the values you listed (14, 3, 3; respectively).

Comment: how can I change the default values of nFastK, nFastD, and nSlowD or make it more smooth? I am trying to make it less sensitive to noise. when I try to include them in the code like this

`addTA(stoch(HLC(XXX)), nFastK=14, nFastD=3, nSlowD=3, smooth=1, col=2:4)`

I get the following error message

`"nFastK" is not a graphical parameter
  "nFastD" is not a graphical parameter
  "nSlowD" is not a graphical parameter
  "smooth" is not a graphical parameter`

Comment: They're parameters to `stoch`, not `addTA`: `addTA(stoch(HLC(x), nFastK=14, nFastD=3, nSlowD=3, smooth=1), col=2:4)`.

Comment: I see, it works now. How should I change the parameters to make it less sensitive to noise? vary `nFastK` or `smooth`?

Comment: It depends on what you want. Read `?TTR::stoch` and the sites in the *References* section.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to make the red line (nFastK) disappear from the plot, so that I can view only the other two?

Comment: @Oposum: sure, just subset the result of the `stoch()` call to only include the columns you want to plot.

Comment: would  you be able to indicate a link / resource where I can figure out how to subset `stoch()`?

Comment: @Oposum: `?Extract`. Seriously, this is very basic.

Comment: I apologize for the questions that seems stupid. I know how to subset regular data in R, I'm just not familiar with quantmod and not sure how to to it in these settings. Thanks for your advice.